# Getting Images From Gallery - Not All "Exist"?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery, filenotfoundexception

I am simply trying to get the path of an image that the user selects and then convert it into a bitmap. The problem is, only some of the images in the gallery work when selected (by "work" I mean they are found to be a file that exists), while the others claim the file does not exist (even though the image is showing up in the gallery?). Even more strange is that this doesn't seem to be consistent, an image that was at one point considered to "exist" now claims to be nonexistent. My code is below:

-----The Intent-----

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY);
```

-----onActivityForResult-----

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri,proj,null,null,null);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();

BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();<br/>
opts.inSampleSize = 2;<br/>
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(column_index),opts);
```

Any ideas on this will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Some images in gallery were loaded from external sources (such as Picasa), thus were not stored locally, causing local filepath reading failure. You can distinguish them by reading your uri value. I could not find a fix for this, perhaps this bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21234 can lure out a solution soon.